# How Do I Fix Visual Studio 2022 Out of Memory Issue?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memory, blazor, blazor-server-side

I went through every possible configuration option I could find both on Stack and in Docs to disable anything remotely extraneous in Visual Studio 2022 running my C# Blazor Server-Side Application.  This mainly meant disabling things such as code in the taskbar and enabling Just My Code options - mostly Text Editor and Debugging Tool options.

When I launch the project, the overall memory load hits ~1.5GB in Task Manager and then I receive out of memory errors despite having nothing else running and 64GB of RAM.  I know that this is due to the inherent memory limits of 64-bit applications, but I thought that VS 2022 was now 64-Bit and thus the limit is supposed to be 4GB and not 2GB.  I did specify a 64-Bit processor only for debugging purposes as well.

I am running on Windows 11, and I cannot get an editbin.exe post build event to work - I have tried multiple examples I found to no avail.  Obviously, I have no Linker options given that this is C#.

Does anybody know how to overcome this issue?

Comment: This is not a specific programming issue and there are no steps to reproduce. Your best bet is to open a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: Make a new BSS project, just the basic counter/weather sample, do nothing else, add no code, just press play. Does it error out? If so, some problem with your install. If not, some problem with your other project (and as you havent given any repro we can't really help)

Comment: Everything was running without issue - and all of my other projects work fine - until I literally added one more Int32 counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I launch the project, the overall memory load hits

This sounds to me that not visual studio is maxing out of memory but your Project.
You can see this in the Diagnostic tools on the right. These show the current resource usage of your project. These are separate from visual studio:
[image]

Eventhough Visual Studio is compiled in 64 Bits, Applications are compiled in 32 bits per default. You can change this the folloring way:

1. In the Drop down `Any CPU` at the top, hit the drop down menu. Any CPU means x86 (32 bit) and x64 (64 bit); x64 processors can also run x86 (32 bit) programs:
   [image]
2. open the `Configuration Manager` from the drop down:
   [image]
3. select the dropdown `platform`. choose `Create New...`
   [image]
4. select `x64` and press `OK`:
   [image]
5. You configuration manager now might look like this (maybe need to apply the active solution platform separately):
   [image]
6. You can now choose between 32 bit and 64 bit on the top:
   [image]

However, most probably, it is a code optimisation issue and not a matter of too little memory. But for that there is not enough information about what your project is trying to archieve

EDIT:

> I was using the Diagnostics view and looking at the memory and I FINALLY found the issue - but no idea how to fix it

You might look into Visual Studios `Performance Profiling`. There are good tutorials on youtube. There is the Performance Profiler and the Memory Profiler.
The Performance Profiler will show you exactly where your Processor is spending it's processing time on whereas the Memory Profiler will show you exactly where the Memory is beeing eaten:
[image]

There are good tutorials on youtube for this. When you are able to locate the issue, feel free to PN me or post something. Detailed information of what you are trying to achieve, where the issue is and about your code is required.

Out of the blue, I would guess you either have a loop filling a list or you are trying to process a vast amount of information.

Comment: Thank you - I was using the Diagnostics view and looking at the memory and I FINALLY found the issue - but no idea how to fix it.  I am marking your response as the answer as this is EXACTLY how to figure things out!